# Why didn’t my credit score fully recover after paying off a collections account?

Tags: credit-score, credit, credit-report

My credit score went down 58 points due to a medical collection account that got reported.

I ended up paying the account in full and submitting a request for it to be removed from my credit report.

The account was removed. My credit reports no longer show any collection accounts, but my score only went back up 20 points.

There aren’t any other factors that I know of that could have caused my score to decrease during the time before I had paid, such as an increase in revolving balances.

At the same time that my score dropped 58 points with credit monitoring services, those services also alerted that I had a collections account added to my report, so I know they were correlated to each other.

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: It doesn't work that way, if you are in arrears and reported, paying in full does not wipe it off your credit report.  You were still late, and  they have every right to continue reporting it as having been paid late... unless you negotiated "remove bad marks"  as part of the settlement.

Comment: So I submitted a written request to the collection agency to stop reporting to the credit bureaus so that the account would be removed and it looks like that’s what happened. I don’t see that account anywhere on my report anymore and don’t see any derogatory marks from them in regards to payments either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't expect that just because something being added to your credit report causes it to dip will mean it automatically rises by an equal amount when that item is expunged from the report.  First and foremost is the assumption that nothing else changed in the meantime, and it also assumes you understand how the credit scoring models work (not meant as an insult, just the observation that most people don't know how the scoring models work in general).

"Pay to remove" certainly helps when resolving collections, but the upside improvement after a collection is removed is frequently much less than peoplpe think it should be, for a variety of reasons which have to do with how the bureaus score credit.

If your credit utilization rose from what it was before then that could cause a more shallow recovery of your score, and the same is true if you opened any new accounts or closed any older ones (affecting average age of accounts).  Did you have any new inquiries, any late pays, changes in address or employment?  All of these can have some impact on your score.  Lastly, if you have what's referred to as a "thin file" score, meaning you don't have a great deal of history, ANY event in your credit profile will have significantly more effect than people with longer, more established credit histories.

Even though most of the mechanisms affecting your score are well known, there are others that aren't precisely because the agencies want to keep the proprietary nature of their scoring models from being gamed any more than possible.

Also keep in mind that if you're using services like CreditKarma or Credit Sesame, those scores are what are referred to "consumer education scores" and may not reflect the precise score of your file.

Finally, there are changes coming to the scoring models, allegedly early in 2022, which are going to have consequences to credit scores because they will use additional non-credit related factors in the scoring algos that might be a boost for people with less credit history.